# Infinite Reload With Rotating State Param in Facebook Application

Tags: facebook, infinite-loop

Infinite Reload With Rotating State Param in my facebook web app, this problem occur suddenly and suddenly all fb app on my server stop working

Page is refreshing again and again and not able to open ,

script work fine in other serverbut fails to work in this , is there any server config to handle facebook app.

You can chk issue at Link - gomandi.com/visit/

State Token is Refreshing again and again in all website hosted in my server , Looks like some Server confiG. issue is there . Can anyone help me with this.as i am my server support team unable to find this issue why my server fails to connect with fb server or viceversa.

SAME APP WORK IN OTHER SERVER !!

Comment: Is this IE only or in any browser? If IE, then it's a server issue, if any browser, then it's a facebook app configuration issue or a coding issue.

Comment: Same App work Fine in Other Server , So No issue with Code ...I am geting this problem in all browser , i know its server issue but unable to find what is the issue and why i am facing this.

Comment: Same domain name on this new server?  Or did you change domain names?

Comment: Yes i Change the domain name in 2nd server.. There are 2 Server   In 1ST Server 3 Domain where no fb apps is working even facebook connect fails .. .. HOSTING COMPANY PROVIDED ME DEMO SERVER to Test apps IN NEW SERVER as they think problem IS IN code  , then in that server also app is not working...but same CODE works in 2nd SERVER (other company server).

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the comments on the question above, what you need to do is to create a brand new app for the different domain names.  So you can have specific URLs for each domain specified in each of the app's app settings.  So if there are three domains, then I'd recommend three apps configured correctly to point to each of those three domains.

Comment: yes , i have tested all config and everthing but app is not working ..looks like facebook support some special config in Server that my server dont support and i dont know what special setting tht was.i am shifted app to new server and there also i am seeing redirect loop u can also chk that at localfresher.com/visit/

Comment: So you didn't mention that you had three different apps in your original question.  You stated you had the "same app".  I'm confused.....

Comment: u can check the issue in url provided even facebook connect not wrking that u can also check at yuplee.in .. u know any specific server setting that stop facebook to connect with server ..

Comment: Since I cannot check your app settings for you, you will need to go into each of the three app settings and ensure the URLs are correct and that they work.  Also check to see if you're not running in sandbox mode on any of them.

Comment: yes , everthing is fine.i have checked . that ..app is working few days back when sql limit crossed and server go down ..when we increased sql limit and again stated app then we face this redirecting look where state token change again and again

Comment: "yes , everthing is fine"  Glad you got it working again.  Congrats!

Comment: no, that is not wroking i said setting are fine..app is wrking few days back not now ..app stop working suddenly due to some change in server but we dont know what changed happend in server